# axios doesnt fetch on refresh, only on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios

So I've been struggling for a while with retrieving data from APIs and or retrieving local json files. I am using React axios but even with the normal fetch method I am having the same issues. When I fetch the endpoint and save the code, my jsx refreshes and the data appears on the screen but then when I refresh the page, it's no longer there and doesn't appear when I refresh again and again. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I tried to retrieve the data on the parent and set it as props but still the same problem.

My child component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import './Card.scss';

import axios from 'axios';

import { ellipsisIcon } from '../../constants/images';

import dataJson from './data.json';

const Card = ({ name, color, icon, currentTime }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const [daily, setDaily] = useState([]);
  const [weekly, setWeekly] = useState([]);
  const [monthly, setMonthly] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('data.json');
      setData(result.data);
      setData(
        data.filter((item) => {
          return item.title === name;
        }),
      );

      setDaily(data[0].timeframes.daily);
      setWeekly(data[0].timeframes.weekly);
      setMonthly(data[0].timeframes.monthly);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="card" style={{ backgroundColor: `${color}` }}>
      <img src={icon} alt={`${name} icon`} />
      <div className="card__container bg-blue">
        <div className="card__top-container flex">
          <p className="text-white ">{name}</p>
          <div className="card__top__elipse-container">
            <img src={ellipsisIcon} alt="ellipsis" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="card__bottom-container">
          {currentTime === 0 && (
            <>
              <h1 className="fs-900 text-white">{daily.current}hrs</h1>
              <div className="card__bottom__prev-container">
                <p className="text-accent ">
                  Yesterday -<span>{daily.previous}hrs</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </>
          )}
          {currentTime === 1 && (
            <>
              <h1 className="fs-900 text-white">{weekly.current}hrs</h1>
              <div className="card__bottom__prev-container">
                <p className="text-accent ">
                  Last Week -<span>{weekly.previous}hrs</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </>
          )}
          {currentTime === 2 && (
            <>
              <h1 className="fs-900 text-white">{monthly.current}hrs</h1>
              <div className="card__bottom__prev-container">
                <p className="text-accent">
                  Last Month -<span>{monthly.previous}hrs</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

My App (Parent):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Card from './components/Card/Card';

import {
  pbImage,
  ellipsisIcon,
  exerciseIcon,
  playIcon,
  careIcon,
  socialIcon,
  studyIcon,
  workIcon,
} from './constants/images';

const cards = [
  {
    name: 'Exercise',
    color: 'hsl(var(--clr-exercise))',
    icon: exerciseIcon,
  },
  {
    name: 'Play',
    color: 'hsl(var(--clr-play))',
    icon: playIcon,
  },
  {
    name: 'Self Care',
    color: 'hsl(var(--clr-care))',
    icon: careIcon,
  },
  {
    name: 'Social',
    color: 'hsl(var(--clr-social))',
    icon: socialIcon,
  },
  {
    name: 'Study',
    color: 'hsl(var(--clr-study))',
    icon: studyIcon,
  },
  {
    name: 'Work',
    color: 'hsl(var(--clr-work))',
    icon: workIcon,
  },
];

function App() {
  const [selectedTime, setSelectedTime] = useState(2);
  return (
    <div className="app bg-dark">
      <div className="main__container grid">
        <div className="side__card-container">
          <div className="side__card__top flex">
            <div className="side__card__top__pb-container">
              <img
                src={pbImage}
                alt="pb"
                className="side__card__top__pb-image pb-image"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="side__card__top__person-container">
              <p className="fs-600 text-accent">Report for</p>
              <h2 className="fs-800 text-white">Jeremy Robson</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="side__card__bottom">
            <div>Daily</div>
            <div>Weekly</div>
            <div>Monthly</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {cards.map((card, _index) => (
          <Card
            key={_index}
            name={card.name}
            color={card.color}
            icon={card.icon}
            currentTime={selectedTime}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you give us more information? Is there any error in the console? Also, you have to consider that states are updated asynchronously. So, you should be careful when you use a state immediately after setting its value.

Comment: @RafaelAbusleme So when I save my code, everything works fine and the values are updated correctly, but when I then press F5 (refresh) in the console, it says that data is not defined and it's like it never feteched the data. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Should I set the state later? I am confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, states are updated asynchronously. So, you should be careful when you use a state immediately after setting its value. In your case, you shouldn’t use the `data` state because you are not sure that it has a value. Try changing to this.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('data.json');
      const filteredData = result.data.filter((item) => {
          return item.title === name;
      })

      setData(filteredData);
      
      // make sure result data isn’t empty
      setDaily(result.data[0].timeframes.daily);
      setWeekly(result.data[0].timeframes.weekly);
      setMonthly(result.data[0].timeframes.monthly);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []); // "[]" makes the useEffect callback only run after the first render
```